# How to publish a AMQP message with Spring to a parking lot queue, after a loop in dead letter queue and TTL in a specific scenario?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I would like to achieve following scenario in my application:

1. If a business error occurs, the message should be send from the incomingQueue to the deadLetter Queue and delayed there for 10 seconds
2. The step number 1 should be repeated 3 times
3. The message should be published to the parkingLot Queue

[image: Scenario to achieve]

[image: Current RabbitMQ Queues setup]

I am able (see the code below) to delay the message for a certain amount of time in a deadLetter Queue. And the message is looped infinitely between the incoming Queue and the deadLetter Queue. So far so good.

**The main question:** How can I intercept the process and manually route the message (as described in the step 3) to the parkingLot Queue for later further analysis?

**A secondary question:** Can I achieve the same process with only one exchange?

Here is a shortened version of my two classes:

**Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
public class MailRabbitMQConfig {

    @Bean
    TopicExchange incomingExchange() {
       TopicExchange incomingExchange = new TopicExchange(incomingExchangeName);
        return incomingExchange;
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange dlExchange() {
        TopicExchange dlExchange = new TopicExchange(deadLetterExchangeName);
        return dlExchange;
    }

    @Bean
    Queue incomingQueue() {

        return QueueBuilder.durable(incomingQueueName)
                .withArgument(
                        "x-dead-letter-exchange",
                        dlExchange().getName()
                )
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue parkingLotQueue() {
        return new Queue(parkingLotQueueName);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding incomingBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder
                .bind(incomingQueue())
                .to(incomingExchange())
                .with("#");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue dlQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder
                .durable(deadLetterQueueName)
                .withArgument("x-message-ttl", 10000)
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", incomingExchange()
                    .getName())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Binding dlBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder
                .bind(dlQueue())
                .to(dlExchange())
                .with("#");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bindParkingLot(
            Queue parkingLotQueue,
            TopicExchange dlExchange
    ) {

        return BindingBuilder.bind(parkingLotQueue)
                    .to(dlExchange)
                    .with(parkingLotRoutingKeyName);
    }
}
```

**Consumer class**

```
@Component
public class Consumer {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${mail.rabbitmq.queue.incoming}")
    public Boolean receivedMessage(MailDataExternalTemplate mailDataExternalTemplate) throws Exception {

        try {
            // business logic here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("Failed to handle a business logic");
        }

        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
}
```

**I know I could define an additional listener for a deadLetter Queue in a Consumer class like that:**

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${mail.rabbitmq.queue.deadletter}")
public void receivedMessageFromDlq(Message failedMessage) throws Exception {
    // Logic to count x-retries header property value and send a failed message manually
    // to the parkingLot Queue
}
```

However it does not work as expected because this listener is called as soon as the message arrives the head of the deadLetter Queue without to be delayed.

Thank you in advance.

---

**EDIT: I was able with @ArtemBilan and @GaryRussell help to solve the problem. The main solution hints are within their comments in the accepted answer. Thank you guys for the help! Below you will find a new diagram that shows the messaging process and the Configuration and the Consumer classes. The main changes were:**

- The definition of the routes between the incoming exchange -> incoming queue and the dead letter exchange -> dead letter queue in the `MailRabbitMQConfig` class.
- The loop handling with the manual publishing of the message to the parking lot queue in the `Consumer` class

[image]

**Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
public class MailRabbitMQConfig {
    @Autowired
    public MailConfigurationProperties properties;

    @Bean
    TopicExchange incomingExchange() {
        TopicExchange incomingExchange = new TopicExchange(properties.getRabbitMQ().getExchange().getIncoming());
        return incomingExchange;
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange dlExchange() {
        TopicExchange dlExchange = new TopicExchange(properties.getRabbitMQ().getExchange().getDeadletter());
        return dlExchange;
    }

    @Bean
    Queue incomingQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(properties.getRabbitMQ().getQueue().getIncoming())
            .withArgument(                 
                properties.getRabbitMQ().getQueue().X_DEAD_LETTER_EXCHANGE_HEADER,
                dlExchange().getName()
            )
            .withArgument(
                properties.getRabbitMQ().getQueue().X_DEAD_LETTER_ROUTING_KEY_HEADER,
                properties.getRabbitMQ().getRoutingKey().getDeadLetter()
            )
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue parkingLotQueue() {
        return new Queue(properties.getRabbitMQ().getQueue().getParkingLot());
    }

    @Bean
    Binding incomingBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder
            .bind(incomingQueue())
            .to(incomingExchange())
            .with(properties.getRabbitMQ().getRoutingKey().getIncoming());
   }

    @Bean
    public Queue dlQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder
            .durable(properties.getRabbitMQ().getQueue().getDeadLetter())
            .withArgument(                      
                properties.getRabbitMQ().getMessages().X_MESSAGE_TTL_HEADER,
                properties.getRabbitMQ().getMessages().getDelayTime()
            )
            .withArgument(
                properties.getRabbitMQ().getQueue().X_DEAD_LETTER_EXCHANGE_HEADER,
                incomingExchange().getName()
            )
            .withArgument(
                properties.getRabbitMQ().getQueue().X_DEAD_LETTER_ROUTING_KEY_HEADER,
                properties.getRabbitMQ().getRoutingKey().getIncoming()
            )
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Binding dlBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder
            .bind(dlQueue())
            .to(dlExchange())
            .with(properties.getRabbitMQ().getRoutingKey().getDeadLetter());
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bindParkingLot(
        Queue parkingLotQueue,
        TopicExchange dlExchange
    ) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(parkingLotQueue)
            .to(dlExchange)
            .with(properties.getRabbitMQ().getRoutingKey().getParkingLot());
    }
}
```

**Consumer class**

```
@Component
public class Consumer {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

    @Autowired
    public MailConfigurationProperties properties;

    @Autowired
    protected EmailClient mailJetEmailClient;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${mail.rabbitmq.queue.incoming}")
    public Boolean receivedMessage(
        @Payload MailDataExternalTemplate mailDataExternalTemplate,
        Message amqpMessage
    ) {
        logger.info("Received message");

        try {
            final EmailTransportWrapper emailTransportWrapper = mailJetEmailClient.convertFrom(mailDataExternalTemplate);

            mailJetEmailClient.sendEmailUsing(emailTransportWrapper);
            logger.info("Successfully sent an E-Mail");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            int count = getXDeathCountFromHeader(amqpMessage);
            logger.debug("x-death count: " + count);

            if (count >= properties.getRabbitMQ().getMessages().getRetryCount()) {
                this.rabbitTemplate.send(
                     properties.getRabbitMQ().getExchange().getDeadletter(),
                     properties.getRabbitMQ().getRoutingKey().getParkingLot(),
                     amqpMessage
                );
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }

            throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("Failed to send an E-Mail");
        }

        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    private int getXDeathCountFromHeader(Message message) {
        Map<String, Object> headers = message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders();
        if (headers.get(properties.getRabbitMQ().getMessages().X_DEATH_HEADER) == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        //noinspection unchecked
        ArrayList<Map<String, ?>> xDeath = (ArrayList<Map<String, ?>>) headers
            .get(properties.getRabbitMQ().getMessages().X_DEATH_HEADER);
        Long count = (Long) xDeath.get(0).get("count");
        return count.intValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delay message to be available in the queue, you should consider to use `DelayedExchange`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#delayed-message-exchange.

As for manually sending to the `parkingLot` queue, that's just easy to use `RabbitTemplate` and send message using its name:

```
/**
 * Send a message to a default exchange with a specific routing key.
 *
 * @param routingKey the routing key
 * @param message a message to send
 * @throws AmqpException if there is a problem
 */
void send(String routingKey, Message message) throws AmqpException;
```

All the queues are bound to the default exchange via their names as routing keys.

Comment: Thank you Artem for the quick response. I have read about the Delayed Message Exchange Plugin (DME) already and tried it. As I thought my scenario is simple and does not need different message delay times, I should use a simple approach with the dead letter queue. Do you think it is safe to use the DME Plugin in production?
The next thing is: How can I intercept the loop between the incoming queue and the deadLetter queue to publish manually the message to the parkingLot queue as suggested by you with:

void send(String routingKey, Message message) throws AmqpException;

Comment: That's fine to use DME as far as I know. If you worry about that, then you definitely can stick with the `TTL` for messages in the `deadLetter`.

Comment: The [Spring Cloud Stream documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#rabbit-dlq-processing) talks about a similar mechanism. It is in the context of processing messages in the DLQ and routing them back to the main queue. In your case, the logic can be in your main listener, with the first leg of the `if` could route the message to the DLQ with the retries header and a TTL. It also has a delayed exchange example.

Comment: And right: you shouldn't consume that `deadLetter` queue.

Comment: You are confusing me a bit the manual part, since according your diagram you don't need to do that as far as your `deadLetter Exchange` is a topic, so you route the same message to several queues. You can route to some other exchange from there, bind queue to it, consume and send to the `parkingLot` queue, but all of this sounds for me as an overhead. You have Topic exchange and you place the same message to several queues. Nothing more to do in between exception and dead letter queue.

Comment: Thank you Gary for the response. To use the interception within the incoming queue listener I will need to change the method signature from my custom type **MailDataExternalTemplate** to the native amqp **Message** type, like that: _public Boolean receivedMessage(Message mailDataExternalTemplate) throws Exception_ So this way I would have an access to the Message Properties / Headers. However I need my object _mailDataExternalTemplate_ to handle the further business logic in the application. How can I cast between the **Message** and the **MailDataExternalTemplate** types?

Comment: You can use both arguments on your listener method: `receivedMessage(@Payload MailDataExternalTemplate mailDataExternalTemplate, Message amqpMessage)`

Comment: @ArtemBilan Good to know. Thank you. If I understand your previous answer correctly you mean I can achieve the same scenario with only one exchange, right?

Comment: Well, I would stick with a separate exchange for the dead letters. And bind that `parkingLot` Queue in parallel with the `deadLetter` Queue. In other words: your picture is an instruction for me to go. There is nothing else to add or overcomplicate.

Comment: @GaryRussell Yeah, I got the Idea with the parking lot in my scenario from the [Spring Cloud Stream documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#rabbit-dlq-processing) documentation. However I was not sure I can use the same approach because the documentation refers to the Spring Cloud Stream (I am new in the Spring world)

Comment: With newer versions (2.0.x), you can separate this logic from your business listener method with a RabbitListenerErrorHandler.